# Does inputting incorrect disk block size in a ddrescue command give errors in recovery?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm creating an image of my 1tb file and used the command:
Sudo dd bs=976624564 if=/dev/sda of='/media/ubuntu/externaldrive/image file.img'

I checked block size with command "sudo cat /proc/partitions" and got the block size above, but when I tried "sudo blockdev--getbsz /dev/sda" I got 4096...

The first command is still running and creating the image of my 1tb disk drive in my external drive, but wanted to know if entering what I feel incorrect will gives errors in recovering data?

Comment: 1. `dd` and `ddrescue` are two different programs; 2. `bs` in the `dd` command line in your question affects only the blocks used by `dd` and should not cause any errors. But it does affect the speed of the operation. Usually people use powers of 2. I often use `bs=4096`. If you want a higher value, you can use 2^20=1048576 (or `bs=1M`), or  2^30=1073741824 (or `bs=1G`).

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` shows the number of blocks (not the block size). You can use for example `sudo parted -ls` to show the logical and physical block size of your mass storage devices (drives). But the blocks used by `dd` must *not* match those block sizes.

Comment: So i shkuld cancel the operation and change bs to 4096 then? Would it be more recommended?

Comment: I think you can let the `dd` operation continue until it finishes. Please post back and share your result ...

Comment: @sudodus That's not a comment!  *That's an answer!*  Ping me back here after the dd finishes and I'll come back and upvote.

Comment: There is not a "correct" block size when using `dd`.